# C++: std::ofstream method open() wipes open ifstream file on second iteration

Tags: c++, iteration, ifstream, ofstream

I am trying to build a "fileUpdater" which will copy an original file into multiple directories, where a file with the same name and extension was previously found.

```
bool update_files(const string inputPath, const vector<string> outputPaths)
{
    ifstream src(inputPath);
    if(!src.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open input file\n" << inputPath <<endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        ofstream dst;
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<= outputPaths.size()-1; i++)
        {
            dst.open(outputPaths[i]);
            try
            {
                dst << src.rdbuf();
                dst.close();
            }
            catch(int e)
            {
                cout << "Unable to replace file\n" <<endl;
                cout << outputPaths[i] <<"\n"<< endl;
                cout << "Error code: " <<e<<endl;
            }
        }
    };
    src.close();
    return true;
}
```

Exactly after executing

```
dst.open(outputPaths[i]);
```

in the second iteration, the original file opened by

```
ifstream src(inputPath);
```

gets wiped and only an empty file is copied into the remaining directories.
I also tried

```
dst.clear();
dst.close();
```

and

```
src.clear();
src.seekg(0,ios::beg);
```

before entering the next iteration, but it made no difference.

**UPDATE**
After trying different files, I realised the behavior depends on the input file. Above behavior appeared for .m-files (MatLab).
After testing it with .txt files, all files were wiped.

Comment: You need to re-open your `src` for each separate `dst`.

Comment: Could I ask you for an explanation?
So simply adding a 'src.open(inputPath)' before I open the next 'dst'  should fix it?

Comment: Simplest, move `ifstream src(inputPath);` inside the `for` loop (you can move `ofstream dst;` in there too).

Comment: Are you sure that `inputPath` is distinct from all the entries in `outputPaths`?

Comment: yes, it's a direct input parameter typed in by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the proposed methods work.
Neither resetting the pointer, nor pulling `ifstream` into the loop, which would result in opening the input file (which is not supposed to change) unnecessarily often.

**It is still unclear** why `dst.open(outputPaths[i]);` is wiping the input file. Also the exact moment of the wipe depends on used types of files.

I implemented following workaround, effectively reading the input file into a string and closing it beforehand, in order to protect it from further read/write action.

```
bool update_files( const string inputPath, const vector<string> outputPaths)
{
    const char * in = inputPath.c_str();
    ifstream src(in);
    if(!src.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open input file\n" << inputPath <<endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        string buffer;
        streamsize s=src.gcount();
        src.seekg(0,ios::end);
        buffer.reserve(src.tellg());
        src.seekg(0,ios::beg);
        buffer.assign((istreambuf_iterator<char>(src)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        src.close();

        for(unsigned int i=0; i<= outputPaths.size()-1; i++)
        {
            const char * out = outputPaths[i].c_str();
            ofstream dst(out);
            try
            {
                dst << buffer;
                dst.close();
            }
            catch(int e)
            {
                cout << "Unable to replace file\n" <<endl;
                cout << outputPaths[i] <<"\n"<< endl;
                cout << "Error code: " <<e<<endl;
            }
        }
    };
    src.close();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're copying the file, with `dst << src.rdbuf();`, will leave the current file position at the end of your input file.  On the second iteration, that same read won't read anything (leaving an empty copy of the file) because you're already at the end of the input file.

The solution is to seek back to the beginning of the input file before every read, using [`seekg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg).  You should call `tellg` before reading anything (right after opening the file), then seek to that position.

```
auto startpos = src.tellg();
ofstream dst;
// ...
src.seekg(startpos);
dst << src.rdbuf();
```

Comment: That did not help, the problem still persists. Even trying to reset the position directly using `src.seekg(0,ios::beg);` before the next `rdbuf()` did not solve the problem.

Comment: @VeljkoLipovac if you go this route and you are not using C++11 or better, you need to clear the error state of the stream. Use `src.clear()` before seeking,